Power Automate - adding items from a list to an Excel table if that item does not already exist in the table
I made a Power Automate flow that should add items from a Sharepoint list to an Excel file. I'm trying to get it to only add items that do not already exist in the table by listing the rows, then for each Sharepoint Item checking to see if the unique Sharepoint ID is present in the Excel table. But instead my flow is adding every item, including the duplicates. I've included pictures of the flow with parameters for the Loop and Condition.
Condition Parameters
For Each Parameters
Tried to only add items not present in excel table, all items are being added instead including duplicates.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Problem is that within a foreach when you're at item() level, you're comparing the value with body/value which is an object. It will certainly 'not contain' the ID you're passing and will always generate a new record.
here an approaches to do this.
Get all IDs in the excel with a select and then check for the ones that dont exist. then add them.

As you see, the condition is now false. Ensure that the datatype of your ID is string (parse it using string() function if not) since select always returns an array of strings.

Better approach
an even better approach to avoid repetitive conditions in the foreach loop is by using a filter array to get all items that don't exist and then create them in the loop.
here's a sample structure using filter array

only six out of 20 were added

